# MSVC 2019: Provide input files as text file to the linker

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, stdin

I use MSVC2019 for two C++ projects:

1. APP is a dynamic link library.
2. TEST is the automated test project.

TEST does not only perform tests on the API part of the DLL, but also on some non-published methods of APP ("unit tests"). Those methods are made visible to the TEST project by linking against the .obj files of the APP project.

Keeping this list of .obj files up-to-date becomes tedious lately. I wondered if there's a way to provide the list of files as input text file to the MSVC linker (see `"Configuration Properties" -> "Linker" -> "Command line" -> "Additional options"`). A script could generate the list of files easily and just pass it to the linker by piping from stdin.

My first attempt failed, simply adding `"< myLinkerArguments.txt"`.

Example:
`PATH_TO_LINKER\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /OUT:"G:\testproject\test_d.exe" < myLinkerArguments.txt`

Any ideas if and how that's possible?

Thank you for reading,
Paul

Answer (score 0):

According to the Microsoft documentation, you could try the following but different approaches:

> The unit tests call non-member functions that aren't exported from the DLL, and the DLL can be built as a static library: Change the DLL project so that it's compiled to a .lib file. Add a separate test project that references the project under test.
>
> This approach has the benefit of allowing your tests to use non-exported members, but still keep the tests in a separate project.

or

> The unit tests must call non-member functions that aren't exported, and the code must be built as a dynamic link library (DLL): Add unit tests in the same project as the product code.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/how-to-write-unit-tests-for-cpp-dlls?view=vs-2022 for more information.

Comment: 1. You have to add new configuration for that, which doubles the amount of configurations. Keeping similar configurations in MSVC in sync is not as straight-forward as I'd like it to be, so I'll have to pass on this one until we switch to CMake builds.

2. Adding test to DLL project isn't really an option, as both projects have grown over time and I'd really like to keep them separated.

Answer (score 0):

I would build a version of the DLL that is identical in every respect but which (also) exports the additional functions you want to test.  Linking these in as separate object files sounds dangerous since then you have two copies - one in the .OBJ file and one in the DLL - and that might very well lead to trouble.

A practical way to achieve this is via a macro, let's call it `EXPORT_FOR_TESTING`, which can be #defined appropriately in the project file that builds the DLL.

So create yourself additional configuration(s) in there, one of which #defines `EXPORT_FOR_TESTING` as `__declspec( dllexport )` and the other one can then define it as empty.  After that, just link your test app with the test DLL and you're done.

Comment: The symbols exported by the DLL are put to a single C-to-C++ conversion layer file, which object file is not imported by the linker of the TEST project. No linker errors so far.Your approach sounds interesting, although adding all those methods is more work than adding the .obj files itself.